# automatic date generating in xsl

Tags: date, xslt

In my style sheet, in header position I have a date column in which the date should be the current date.

How can I do that?

**My xsl file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"

<fo:table-row>
    <fo:table-cell border="solid" border-width="1pt" padding-left="-7mm">
        <fo:block>
            DATE
        </fo:block>
    </fo:table-cell>
    <fo:table-cell border="solid" border-width="1pt" padding-left="-9mm">
        <fo:block>

            current date should come here

        </fo:block>
    </fo:table-cell>
</fo:table-row>
```

Comment: Why is your stylesheet missing the most important piece here: the version of XSLT you are using?

Answer (score 2):

For XSLT 1 you can use this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="document(&apos;http://xobjex.com/service/date.xsl&apos;)/date/utc/@rfc-822"/>
```

You can then use substrings or an xsl:choose to format the date to your needs

Comment: i used this. but i am getting error, Fo transformation failed

Comment: Suspect it's a problem elsewhere in your stylesheet? Your sample code is missing a > from the end of the namespace declaration. Does it compile ok without the date call in?

Comment: yes. the compilation is gng smoothly with out the date call

Comment: +1, nice idea. You don't need the `&apos;` thing, though - a simple (unescaped) single quote will do just fine.

Comment: @ramu246 Should work, but I confess I've not used it with xsl-fo. Some Googleing says you may need to allow document() functions [http://forums.asp.net/post/3194504.aspx](http://forums.asp.net/post/3194504.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

**XSL Version 2.0 :**

```
    <fo:block>
        <xsl:value-of  select="current-dateTime()"/>
    </fo:block>
```

Format DateTime :

```
  <xsl:value-of select="format-dateTime(current-dateTime(),'[D]-[MN]-[Y] [FN] at [H]:[m01]:[s01]')"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I have used that code. But when I am doing transformation, the transformation is failed and showing the error as format-datetime is not a valid XSLT or Xpath function

Answer (score 1):

If you are using **XSLT 1.0**, you need to either:

(1) Pass the current date to the stylesheet as a **parameter** during runtime;

or

(2) Use the [EXSLT date:date-time() **extension function**](http://www.exslt.org/date/functions/date-time/index.html), which most (but not all) XSLT 1.0 processors support.